# Excel and VBA form editing only

Tags: excel, vba, forms

I've been trying to produce a form for the company I work at to automatically produce a specification with information inputted using excels form control drop down boxes and buttons. I have managed to produce the code that produces the required results but was just wondering if it is possible to make it so that the user can only choose from the drop down menus and press the buttons. I have seen that parts of the spreadsheet can be locked but I have struggled when trying to use this on all of my drop down boxes and buttons. I would also like to make it so the inputs (drop down boxes) are within another window maybe? Or if there is a way the inputs could pop up as a form outside of excel in order to make it look more professional. What the sheet looks like at the moment is below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: To me it is not clear, if the screenshot is from a worksheet or from a user form ...

Comment: It is from a work sheet, sorry I was trying to show what I want it to look like